# Q: How to intercept GoogleMap's requestAnimationFrame using Zone.js

Tags: google-maps, zone.js

***EDIT: I'm using Zone v0.8.20***

Background: Google Maps triggers `requestAnimationFrame` when zooming out of the map and when panning, I want to intercept these `requestAnimationFrame` via Zone.js to debounce it and may be improve performance on mobile devices...

I have the following simple repro code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;

      var mapZone = Zone.current.fork({
          name: "GMAPS",
          onScheduleTask: (delegate, current, target, task) => {
                console.log(task);
                console.log(Zone.current.name)
                return delegate.scheduleTask(target, task);
            },
            onHasTask: (delegate, current, target, task) => {
                console.log(task)
            }
      })
      function initMap() {
        mapZone.run(() => {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 8
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: -34.100, lng: 150.644},
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
            });
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap&sensor=true"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem here is that I can't seem to intercept the `requestAnimationFrame` on the `onScheduleTask` method defined on the ZoneSpec... as you can see on the code, I ran the instantiation of Google Maps inside the forked Zone called `mapZone`

I'm newbie on Zone.js, this probably might be a simple problem, but I can't seem to find a solution... what do you think am I missing here?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score -1):

the reason that it is not work because google map is loaded in root zone, and in current version of zone.js, there are no way to configure the root zone spec.

I have created a walk around about this one to config root zone by monkey-patch zone.js. you can find the working sample in below link.

https://github.com/JiaLiPassion/customize-root-zone

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19116949)

Comment: sure, thank you for the advice, I will update my answer.